# SMTP Headers Guide

Tags: email, smtp, spam-prevention, headers

Is there a guide/cheat sheet that explains Email/SMTP headers in detail?
I could not find any useful resources after plenty of Googling.

The purpose is to understand the headers in order to be able to create advanced custom anti SPAM filters (not just based on common subjects and source IP addresses).

Comment: "Questions seeking product, service, or learning material recommendations are off-topic because they become outdated quickly and attract opinion-based answers. Instead, describe your situation and the specific problem you're trying to solve. Share your research."

Answer (score 1):

Actually the headers belongs to Mail Messages. Optional headers are usually added by SMTP and relay servers to the original message, but those are related to individual server/technology.
The standard definition of `Internet Message Format` is described in the RFC 2822 in which you can find the standard `fields`. Here a link to [RFC2822](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc2822.html)

Comment: RFC2822 has been updated, and the latest version RFC is 5322. https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5322